# Minimum moves (not swaps) to make two arrays equal

Tags: python, algorithm

It sounds this topic is a duplicate but it's not.

I have two arrays like these:

```
a = ['B', 'C', 'A']
b = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I need to know minimum moves (not swaps) to make `a` equal to `b`. With swapping approach, the minimum swaps is 2, but I need minimum moves (which in this case is 1; by moving `'A'` to the front of list.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I don't mean replacing. If you grab and put `'A'` at the front of list, `a` will be equal to `b`

Comment: Yes, You are right!

Comment: can you move an element from middle?

Comment: @Kaidul yes, you can move any element to anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems `N-LCS(a,b)`

N is the length of array

LCS is Longest Common Subsequence

Let elements in LCS have a CORRECT position. For the elements not in LCS, you can correct its position by just one move.